# How do I prevent my git from corrupting?

Tags: git, virtual-machine, vmware, corruption

I am working off of VMWare's virtual ubuntu 16.04 environment on an android studio project. The git is set up normally and works most of the time but I occasionally (at least three times in the past two months) get a corrupted git.

```
error: object file .git/objects/bb/2b004268181780ddea02ea4313142fc36a0541 is empty
error: object file .git/objects/bb/2b004268181780ddea02ea4313142fc36a0541 is empty
fatal: loose object bb2b004268181780ddea02ea4313142fc36a0541 (stored in .git/objects/bb/2b004268181780ddea02ea4313142fc36a0541) is corrupt
```

I am not asking how to fix those errors, I've already fixed them a couple times but they keep happening and it's really annoying and time consuming to fix. What is causing this to happen?

My normal day with git is to open VMWare, log into my virtual machine, and open up android studio, I don't touch git until the end of the day. I end the day one of two ways.

1. I click `File -> Exit` on Android Studio, git commit stuff, then close VMWare. Then I shut down the desktop.
2. Same as 1 except I leave VMWare open, I don't git commit that day, `Ctrl-alt-del` and set the desktop to locked mode.

Or some variation of the two.

I usually encounter the corruption at the end of the day when I try to commit.

[image: Hard Disk Settings]

Additional VMWare settings:

- [Hardware settings of my virtual machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc2U6.png)
- [Virtual machine options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizwH.png)

Comment: Just guessing this has to do with virtual storage. Can you provide the details for the file system? Is the git repo saved to a network share or an elastic vhd?

Comment: I don't know what those two options mean, the git repo is on Bitbucket and I've cloned it to my virtual machine's Documents folder

Comment: Your virtual machine has virtual storage, and you can configure options for that in vmware when creating the machine. Since you say it's in my docs, then I'm pretty sure that's not a network share. So elastic storage is the option to have a fixed vhd size that allocates the full size on the physical disk or to spoof it to the guest machine only giving it what it actually needs.

Comment: I added images of my VM settings to the question but I'm pretty sure mine is set up with elastic storage given your definition.

Comment: Could you show the settings for `Hard Disk (SCSI) 20 GB`

Comment: A couple things jump out to me. 1) your disk appears to only have 400MB free space, and running that low can often lead to quirky problems. 2) `Disk space is not preallocated for this hard disk. Hard disk contents are stored in multiple files` is what I meant by elastic. You won't be able to change that while it's running, and I'm not sure if you're able to change that at all - you might have to start over with a fresh disk. But, try bumping up the size first a few more GB and see if that helps. If not, then try to use a fixed size preallocated disk.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll try those things out and see if it happens again in the next few weeks/months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new VM that has twice the size and the problem hasn't occurred since then so I'm going to go ahead and assume that's the answer. If I see it again I'll update this.

Comment: Any updates? It has been over a year, did you encounter git corruptions?

Comment: No corruptions up to the time I left the company, about a year.

Answer (score 3):

For those having the problem and disk size is not the issue this may help: I was powering down my machine and I kept getting git repo errors (I also noticed multiple journal recoveries on start up).  I then tried Sending the Shutdown signal via the File menu; it indicated I had open files. I suspect the Shutdown allowed those files to close; I suspect some of them were git repo files.

That got rid of the journaling errors and so far I have not seen any git repo errors.  Probably better is the ACPI Shutdown menu option under the Machine menu.